# How to edit a particular line and replace text via sed in linux (cent os)

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

```
Width                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                   : 720 pixels
```

I'm working on a bash script and need to filter video on the bases of resolution.
Like 
If Width is greater than equal to 1280 then HD
else
Non HD

I'm using mediainfo to make and save info in txt file.

```
cat /home/The.txt | grep "Width"  |  awk -F ':' '{print $2}' | grep -o "[0-9]*"
```

output of this is

```
1
280
```

this is because of one " " between 1 280

For height its alright if i grep height.

Is there anyway I can edit the line of width and make all integers like

```
1100
1280
1272
```

from

```
1 110
1 280
1 272
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use:

```
grep "Width" /home/The.txt | tr -cd '0-9\n'
```